# Configurable child products show as backorder on order confirmation

Tags: configurable-product, stock, order-email

I have a lot of configurable products on my site and have a problem and that is:

When a customer places an order of a child product of a configurable product the order confirmation show the child product as backorder / out of stock.

Is there a way to fix this issues?

I use Magento 2 2.4.5-p1.

Not the best to show the customers.

Comment: you need to set the quantity of child products too, it looks like the back order is enabled and the child products quantity is zero.

Comment: I have added the child products to the configurable products manualy with products I have made myself and they all have in stock and quantity above 0.

Comment: and yes backorder is enable